# How do I import Axios into main.js in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, import, axios

I seem to not be able to use axios in my vue project as it's saying that 'axios' is not defined when I try using `axios.get()` in my file for **Home.vue**. Am I doing something wrong in main.js where I configure it? Or am I missing something that needs to be added? Below is my code for `main.js` and it shows how I'm adding axios to my project.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import GSignInButton from 'vue-google-signin-button';
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import axios from 'axios';
import './assets/element-variables.scss';
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(ElementUI, { locale });
Vue.use(GSignInButton);
Vue.use(axios);
Vue.use(ElementUI);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

**Edit:** The solution for this issue for me was to install a vue plugin called vue-axios and follow the steps to configure here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios

Comment: did you try out `this.axios.get()` or `this.$axios.get()`?

Comment: Just checking: have you installed the dependency node module for axios?

Comment: Instead of `Vue.use(axios);` do `window.axios = axios;` which makes axios globally accessible, otherwise use [this vue plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios) which integrates axios into your vue app as the normal axios is not a vue plugin, so `Vue.use` won't work.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir thanks the plugin worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `axios` as instance global property instead of `Vue.use(axios);`:

```
Vue.prototype.$axios=axios
```

then you could use it in any child component like `this.$axios.get()`

learn more about [adding-instance-properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#The-Context-of-Prototype-Methods)

Comment: this is a vue 3 syntax